# jQuery function not working in MVC4 _Layout.cshtml page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code in an MVC4 project's `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` file (MVC MasterPage)

```
<span id="clickMeToToggleMe">
    <img src="~/Images/1.jpg" />
</span>
```

I also have a `~/Scripts/myCustom.js` Javascript file bundled under `~/Scripts/jQuery-1.8.3.min` in my `~/ViewStart/bundle.config` file. The "myCustom.js" file contains multiple other functions that are working as they should when I run the application and `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` view is rendered in the browser.

**The problem**:
 Even though I've confirmed that the view and the javascript is rendering and functioning as it should ...one specific Javascript/jQuery function isn't working:

```
// bg toggle
$('#clickMeToToggleMe').click(function () { $('body').toggleClass('anotherClass', 1000); });
```

I know this works because I've used it numerous times in the past. Here's a ***[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrbilljsf/3mQDV/3/)*** where they used it too. For some reason the function isn't working in the `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`, any ideas?

***UPDATE #1***
The following image shows the selector and element (including forced Padding due to the height of the image vs the line-height) in FireFox (using the Inspect Element (Q) selection tool):
[image]
I changed the name of the span Id to "tb" (as well as the selector in the javascript*

Comment: any error shows up in console ?

Comment: None. I've ran the page at least 30 times through both Firebug and Web Developer Toolbar in FireFox and a number of times through Internet Explorer and Chrome, no errors (that I can see) are being thrown.

Comment: If you throw in a breakpoint does the code at least get hit?

Comment: Good point. What I found is that **NO**, when I place a breakpoint on the toggle() posted above and click the `<span id="clickMeToToggleMe"...` the debugger doesn't break. However **YES** the debugger breaks if I drop a break point on one of the other functions in the script (a `('#el').hover(...` function). grrraaaaa!

Comment: If you're using styling with the span, is it possible you're not clicking on it and instead clicking on the `<img>`? Floating etc could be messing with your DOM. Use en element inspector to find the span and make sure it wraps around the `<img>` and that you're actually clicking on it.

Comment: RowanFreeman I've updated my post with an image of the element in the browser. We see that there is padding around the span. But as in the  JsFiddle example we know that we can click either in the `<span>` tag or the `<img>`. I guess you'll have to simply take my word for it that I am without question clicking within both the `<span>` and at other times within the `<img>`.

Comment: Is the code publicly available? I'm out of ideas without seeing it.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Further I've restarted my computer and ran CCleaner and it's not a compilation bug. Thanks for looking at this for me Rowan have a good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buggy installation, evidently my new install of Visual Studio 2012 Professional (purchased (finally)) was bugging out on me. In my troubleshooting and cleaning out my computer I uninstalled Visual Web Developer 2012 and ran my solution again and the function now works as it should, waste of time! Thanks all that tried to help.